# Using RotatingFileHandler to log from multiple processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-logging

I am using the multiprocessing module to split many I/O jobs across different processes and I encountered the problem of logging from the different processes to the same log file.
After looking for a solution I changed the file set in the logger from a normal FileHandler to a RotatingFileHandler.
During my experiments (in the dev envr.) it worked perfectly and solved the problem, but I'm not sure it is a reliable approach.
Is there any downside? Something I should be aware of?

Comment: One solution is to use an external messaging queue service like RabbitMQ to push all your logs to, and then have one consumer process that polls and siphons the log messages to a single log. here is a python library for this: https://pypi.org/project/python-logging-rabbitmq/

Answer (score 0):

No it is not supported. From python [logging cookbook](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes):

> Although logging is thread-safe, and logging to a single file from
> multiple threads in a single process is supported, **logging to a single
> file from multiple processes is not supported**, because there is no
> standard way to serialize access to a single file across multiple
> processes in Python.

Afterwards the cookbook suggests to use a single socket-server process that handles the logs and the other processes sending log messages to it.
There is a working example of this apporach in the section [Sending and Receiving logging events across a network](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network).

you may make a api that receives your logs and save in a file. or you can use a queue to store your logs all threads puts in this queue the disered log and a separate process that reads its queue write it on a file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did read the docs and also other answers about the topic. The point is that it is working, somehow and i want to understand why it is working and what may happen.

Comment: you may crash your log write process when you have two processes accessing the same file ate same time. im my codes i use a queue that organize logs and all processes save on it and i have another process that consume the queue data and store it on a file ( and only this process writes this file )

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've been struggling with the implementation. I tried to create a well documented question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68207921/12560646 . Feel free to check it out.