# QueueHandler for multiprocessing logging

Tags: python, logging, python-multiprocessing, python-logging

I'm trying to adapt my program to log from different processes to a single log file.
I have been looking for a solution for many days without success. I think I still don't understand how the queue handler works. In my mind the process was like:

- create q
- add qHandler to the main logger
- all the logs will be redirect to the q which will then use the other handlers attached to the logger (through logger.handle(record)).
  I created a simplified version of the program to illustrate how the loggers behaves

```
# logger.py

import logging
   
def listener_configurer():
    """This sets the settings for the root logger. The highest in the hierarchy. 
    All the handlers added to this root logger are available for all the subloggers.
    """
    root = logging.getLogger('main')
    file = logging.FileHandler(r'logs\temp.log', 'w')
    fmt = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(processName)-10s %(name)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    stream = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream.setFormatter(fmt)
    file.setFormatter(fmt)
    root.addHandler(file)
    root.addHandler(stream)
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def listener_process(queue):
    listener_configurer()
    while True:
        try:
            record = queue.get()
            if record is not None:
                print("-------------- using q ------------------ " + record.name + " -> " + record.message)
                logger = logging.getLogger(record.name)
                logger.handle(record)
            else:
                break
        except Exception:
            import sys, traceback
            logger.error('Whoops! Problem: %s', "problem", exc_info=1)
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)
```

```
# saver.py (worker)
import logging
import typing

log = logging.getLogger('main.Saver')

class Saver:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        log.warning("Instantiating a saver obj")
       
    def doStuff(self, input_line: typing.Tuple,) -> None:
        log.info(f"Exporting: {input_line}") # ASSUMING A TUPLE AS INPUT like: email, email_id, email_url
        (email, email_id, email_url, *other) = input_line
        log.info("Source URL: " + email_url)
        log.info(f"EmailName: {email}")
        log.warning(f"EmailID: {email_id}")
        log.debug("Exporting done!")
```

```
# manager.py
import logging
import logging.config
import logging.handlers
import multiprocessing
import logger
from saver import Saver

class Manager:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        ### LOGGER
        # initializing listener -> this queue is going to be used for the multiprocessing logging
        self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue(-1)
        self.log = self.root_configurer(self.queue)  # getting a reference to the root logger -> used to log from this module
        self.listener = multiprocessing.Process(target=logger.listener_process, args=(self.queue,))
        self.listener.start()
        # utils
        self.log.info(f"Starting program at 10 am")
        # instantiate
        self.save = Saver()

    def root_configurer(self, queue):
        root = logging.getLogger('main')
        h = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(queue)  # Just the one handler needed
        root.setLevel(DEBUG)
        root.addHandler(h)
        return root # this is the main function -> we need to retrieve the root logger here

    def run(self):
        tuples = [("email1","id1","url1",""), ("email2","id2","url2",""), ("email3","id3","url3",""), ("email4","id4","url4",""), ("email4","id4","url4","")]
        procs = []
        for res in tuples:
            proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.save.doStuff, args=(res,)) 
            procs.append(proc)
            proc.start()
        # complete the processes
        for proc in procs:
            proc.join()
        
        self.log.debug("We reached this part!")
        # close listener
        self.queue.put_nowait(None)
        self.listener.join()   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = Manager()
    m.run()
```

what I would expect is a bunch of lines like:

```
-------- using q -------------  main.saver INFO Source URL: ...
-------- using q -------------  main.saver INFO EmailName ...
-------- using q -------------  main.saver WARNING EmailID
-------- using q -------------  main.saver DEBUG ....
```

plus all these lines written to the log. For some reason I get:

```
EmailID: id4
EmailID: id3
EmailID: id2
-------------- using q ------------------ main -> Starting program at 10 am
2021-07-01 11:42:16,385 MainProcess main INFO     Starting program at 10 am      
-------------- using q ------------------ main.Saver -> Instantiating a saver obj
2021-07-01 11:42:16,386 MainProcess main.Saver WARNING  Instantiating a saver obj
EmailID: id4
EmailID: id1
-------------- using q ------------------ main -> We reached this part!
2021-07-01 11:42:16,852 MainProcess main DEBUG    We reached this part!
```

and a file like:

```
2021-07-01 11:42:16,385 MainProcess main INFO     Starting program at 10 am
2021-07-01 11:42:16,386 MainProcess main.Saver WARNING  Instantiating a saver obj
2021-07-01 11:42:16,852 MainProcess main DEBUG    We reached this part!
```

Any idea?

***EDIT***
the code was taken from a mix of:

- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#a-more-elaborate-multiprocessing-example

and

- https://fanchenbao.medium.com/python3-logging-with-multiprocessing-f51f460b8778

Answer (score 1):

Your workers do not write to the queue.

Your code seems to be based upon the Loging Cookbook's [Logging to a single file from multiple processes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes). You can see there that the workers take the queue as parameter, to configure themselves with (through `worker_configurer`). In your code you only configure your Manager, not your Workers.

Just adding `self.queue` to the Process args and copying the (slightly edited) `root_configurer` method into the `saver.py` to be called when `doStuff` starts, sufficed to work as intended.

Out of subject nitpicks (that you did not asked for, but they are free !) :

- The "root logger" is unnamed, you get it by doing `logging.getLogger()` (without parameter). The logger `"main"` is thus not the root. Consider calling it `main_logger` instead.
- Keep the comment for why you `break` out of the loop when `record is None`, I thought at first it was a mistake.
- If the first time you `get` a record from the queue an error occurs, you never set the `logger` variable so your exception handler will raise an `UnboundLocalError` before it gets written to stderr.
- Credit code that you did not write : what you submitted is very largely based on the Logging Cookbook example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your suggested edit. 
I used the second link in the edit as main reference and there the configurer is treated a bit differently. 
Nonetheless, I'll try to apply the changes you suggested. Thanks.